# Selecting image for embedded youtube video

Tags: media

Would like to know how to select the image that is shown on the web page for an embedded youtube video. Currently an image from the video seems to be randomly pulled out and used.

Comment: I believe this is done through the YouTube control panel rather than through your embed code in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you cant if its not your video. This is chosen either by youtube or if your a youtube partner you can upload your own image (I think they have a tool nowadays which lets regular youtube users choose their thumbnail for their video).

If you visit this page:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc

You will see down the page there is a default/hqdefault thumbnail that comes with every video feed.